# Change a matrix to long string in a matrix to elements

Tags: python

I have the following matrix:

```
matrix= [['  0.9111 0.9082 0.9151 0.9023 0.9019 0.9106'],
         [' 0.7488 114*0 0.7646 0.7594 0.7533 117*0/'],
         []]
```

I am trying to convert it to the following form:

```
[['0.9111', '0.9082', '0.9151', '0.9023', '0.9019', '0.9106'], 
 ['0.7488',  '114*0', '0.7646', '0.7594', '0.7533', '117*0']]
```

I tried different functions like:

```
list(zip((row.split() for row in matrix)))

updated_matrix = [x.strip() for x in matrix]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter out empty lists and split the 1st item in sublists:

```
matrix= [[' 0.9111 0.9082 0.9151 0.9023 0.9019 0.9106'], [' 0.7488 1140 0.7646 0.7594 0.7533 1170/'], []]
matrix = [m[0].rstrip('/').split() for m in matrix if m]
print(matrix)
```

---

```
[['0.9111', '0.9082', '0.9151', '0.9023', '0.9019', '0.9106'], ['0.7488', '1140', '0.7646', '0.7594', '0.7533', '1170']]
```